# Make a python project with tkinter executable

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

Render a project (project) made up of several python scripts and under folders also containing python scripts or not executable (python 2.7)

I used the following code to make my project executable: `pyinstaller intercomplete.py` (intercomplete.py is the script I run using anaconda spyder to launch the GUI), but it gives the following traceback:

```
hiddenimports = pytest.freeze_includes ()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'freeze_includes' for the code is too large
```

Salam everyone here is my problem, I created a program project under python and tkinter, this program consists of several Python scripts contained in a folder, and next to these python scripts there are subfolders that contain other python scripts and subfolders allow the recording of data processed by the program as text files, png images, pdf images and Excel tables, there is a main script called intercomplete.py.

It is running and displays a graphical interface that allows clicking on the menu commands and buttons to call the other python scripts that I quoted at the top, I want to make this program executable but I do not know how to proceed with pyinstaller that I installed (pyinstaller3.5).

Could you help me make this executable because I need it for my doctorate and thank you, sorry if my English is not good because I just use the translator online.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `function` to compile your script to executable

```
pyinstaller --windowed --onefile   intercomplete.py
```

It will create a dist folder which contains exe named `intercomplete.exe` file run it.

Comment: give me feedback after doing that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer here I did what you asked me but still I get this traceback:     
        hiddenimports = pytest.freeze_includes()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'freeze_includes'
I do not understand what is the problem especially the last two lines of Traceback at the top
if anyone has the answer or solution I will be grateful
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer here I did what you asked me but still I get this traceback: hiddenimports = pytest.freeze_includes() AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'freeze_includes' I do not understand what is the problem especially the last two lines of Traceback at the top if anyone has the answer or solution I will be grateful thank you –